# Be notified when an Ethereum event occurs

Tags: events, erc-20-approve

I recently asked another question, but I deleted that one because I can narrow down my question to something simpler.

Suppose an ethereum ERC-20 token contract can emit the following event:

```
event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
```

Is there a service (paid or free) I can use to watch for this event and be notified preferably by SMS (or email) whenever it is emitted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use the Tenderly.co service.  It does not offer SMS notifications, but there are other options that will have to do for now, such as email.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [OpenZeppelin Defender](https://openzeppelin.com/defender/) it has a **Sentinels** functionality that allows to monitor a deployed contract, and you can choose to be notified via Email, Slack, Telegram, or Discord, push data to Datadog, or execute an Autotask in response to a notification.

*Note: I'm not affiliated with the products mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  Hadn't heard about this.  I'm willing to pay for the service but from their pricing table they have no individual plan with mainnet access.  I would need the "Teams" plan which is $500/month.  Too rich for my blood.  Have you heard of tenderly.co?  They are built with monitoring/alerts in mind, have a 14 day trial and $80/month gets it done.  Am not affiliated, but trying it just now. Only downside might be no SMS notification